# My app throws me method was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

I made an app and I create a simple logic. But when I run it it throws me

```
The method '>' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: >(25)
```

I mean is a basic math comparison, I don't know why it throws me that, here's my file

```
import 'dart:math';

class CalculatorBrain {
  CalculatorBrain({this.height, this.weight});

  final int height;
  final int weight;

  double _bmi;

  String calculateBMI() {
    double _bmi = weight / pow(height / 100, 2);
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }

  String getResult() {
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'Overweight';
    } else if (_bmi > 18.5) {
      return 'Normal';
    } else {
      return 'Underweight';
    }
  }

  String getInterpretation() {
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'You have a higher than normal body weight. Try to exercise more';
    } else if (_bmi > 18.5) {
      return 'You have a normal body weight. Good job!';
    } else {
      return 'You have aa lower than normal body weight. You can eat a bit more.';
    }
  }
}
```

Can you help me understand this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `calculateBMI()` you declare new local variable `_bmi` by declaring its type, so `_bmi` field of class `CalculatorBrain` is still null. Just remove type declaration of `_bmi` variable in `calculateBMI()`.
You can also change `calculateBMI()` into getter and remove `_bmi` field completely. And mark `height` and `weight` as a required. Also you can add assertions to make sure this values is greater than 0 and are not null.

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'meta'; 


class CalculatorBrain {
  CalculatorBrain({@required this.height,
                   @required  this.weight,
                  }) : assert(height > 0), assert(weight > 0);
  final int height;
  final int weight;


  double get _bmi => weight / pow(height / 100, 2);

  String getResult() {
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'Overweight';
    } else if (_bmi > 18.5) {
      return 'Normal';
    } else {
      return 'Underweight';
    }
  }

  String getInterpretation() {
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'You have a higher than normal body weight. Try to exercise more';
    } else if (_bmi > 18.5) {
      return 'You have a normal body weight. Good job!';
    } else {
      return 'You have aa lower than normal body weight. You can eat a bit more.';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are calling `getResult()` or `getInterpretation()` before asigning a value to `_bmi`.

To prevent this, you might want to check if `_bmi` is `null` before comparing it. Here is an example for your `getResult` function:

```
String getResult() {
  if (_ bmi != null){
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'Overweight';
    } else if (_bmi > 18.5) {
      return 'Normal';
    } else {
      return 'Underweight';
    }
  }
}
```